# Bitcoin Recovery

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I purchased Bitcoins to make a purchase, I sent the bitcoin to my Electrum wallet and later started to make the purchase. When I checked the vendor their system timed out, but Transaction ID screen in the Electrum wallet is still running conformations, with my bitcoin floating around somewhere. Is there a way to recover the bitcoin. The merchant where the attempted purchase was made does not have a wallet onsite.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Answer (score 1):

> **with my bitcoin floating around somewhere.**

The Blockchain is the definitive record of where that money is. Once there are about six confirmations there is no reasonable doubt about who now has control over that money

Bitcoins don't really float about anywhere indeterminate. They are either under your control or under the recipient's control.

I believe there is the possibility of a fork in the blockchain and for the network to converge on a fork that has your transaction in a slightly later block than your wallet initially indicated - but that's relatively rare and I suspect wouldn't make any difference after an hour or so in most cases.

> **Is there a way to recover the bitcoin.**

After six or so confirmations, the only feasible way is to ask the recipient if they are willing to return the money to you.